# Using boost without having to set up an environment

Tags: c++, boost

Is there a way to use C++ boost libraries without having the set up an environment?

I am trying to use `boost::split` but am getting errors because `boost::split` could not find other dependent files.

I know how to set up the environment with CMake/VS, but this is just a light weight utility program, so there's no need to do that.

Is there a way to just use `boost` libraries on the fly?

I am aware that much of boost is header-only, but I have received the following error, which is confusing me:

`C:\Development\Libraries\boost_1_50_0\boost\algorithm\string.hpp:18:60: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/std_containe
rs_traits.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Comment: [`boost::split` is header-only](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/string_algo/env.html), no linking required. You're going to need to give more details about the problem you're having.

Comment: If boost is not installed as in the standard location. Then you can specify it with `-I<absolute path of boost>` that should work for gcc and cl1.

Comment: I am aware that boost is header only and all you have to do it include the particular file, but I am getting the following error, so I am now confused: `C:\Development\Libraries\boost_1_50_0\boost\algorithm\string.hpp:18:60: fatal error: boost/algorithm/string/std_containe
rs_traits.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously this will only work for header-only libraries. You need more stuff for the boost-libraries that come with files to link.

Now, I'm doing just that: I use some of the boost header libraries, none of the link libraries, and I don't need any preparation for that. EXCEPT that boost includes some of its headers with <filename> instead of "filename", so you HAVE to add the boost library directory to the search path for include files. Nothing else should be required.

EDIT: except possibly for an adjustment to your warning settings. Unfortunately, boost is not "warning clear", which conflicts with my -Werror and /WX switches. I had to disable some warnings globally because there were just too many of them (and warning pragmas don't work with precompiled headers on all platforms), and fixed a few inside the boost headers.

Comment: I am using Notepad++, is there a way to let Notepad++ know of the directory?

Comment: @czchlong Notepad++ is an editor. It is your build system/program that needs to know the include directories and library search paths.

Comment: @czchlong: You are invoking the compiler from `Notepad++`?

Comment: @LokiAstari, No, I am using the terminal with `G++`. So, `g++ filename.cpp`

Comment: @czchlong: `g++ -IC:\Development\Libraries\boost_1_50_0\ filename.cpp`

Comment: @czchlong: Edit your question add everything from out discussion to it. I believe you are leaving something out. As that will work given the details of the question as I understand it. Thus there is something missing from this conversation that somebody else may see.